# While doesn't approve true requirement

Tags: c#

Variable i will be 0 in the end. Am I having serious problem in visual studio or in my brain?

```
double value = 0.0001;

int i = 0;

while(value < 0)
{
        value *= 10;
        i++;
}

Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: check your brain

Comment: `0.0001` is greater than 0.

Comment: `a < b` is true if `a` is *less-than* `b`

Comment: Okay I will probably delete this post...

Comment: what are you even trying to accomplish? I am totally confused by the purpose of this code.

Comment: I was in trip that 0.0001 is not greater than 0. Dumb question, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd If he had `while(value > 0)`, and changed it to `value /= 10`, then it would show the number of iterations until you run out of `double` precision (from a starting number), I think anyways.. I did that and it was 320 iterations for me. So I guess I learned to not divide .00001 by 10 more than 319 times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code inside the while block never runs because your while condition is actually false.

Your condition:
`0.0001 < 0`

This is a false statement so the while block is skipped.